# What kind of logarithm does $\log$ mean in Wikipedia articles?

Tags: terminology, data-mining

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but what what type of logarithm is $\log$ in Wikipedia articles? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the situation. For a mathematician, $\log n$ probably means the natural logarithm. For a computer scientist, $\log n$ probably denotes the base $2$ logarithm, etc.

I think sometimes people write $\ln x$ for the natural logarithm, $\lg x$ for the base $2$ logarithm and $\log x$ for the base $10$ logarithm.

For programming languages such as Matlab, Python, Julia, $\log x$ means the natural logarithm of $x$.

Do you have a specific Wikipedia article that contains $\log$?

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: I think for that article, the base of the logarithm does not matter. See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.97.7340&type=pdf&rep=rep1).

Comment: I deleted your "This is intended to be a comment" disclaimer, since this is the answer.

Comment: For a computer scientist, $\log$ doesn't always mean base-$2$. Like everything else, it depends on context. For example, I'm a computer scientist but I work with probability as well as numbers of bits so I would guess I actually use natural and base-2 logs equally often.

Comment: @zbir Thanks for a nice paper(I use Stanford Information Retrieval). That's what come in to my mind, after I posted it, that it may not matter:)

Answer (score 6):

**It depends entirely on context.** In mathematics as a whole, $\log$ usually denotes the natural logarithm (base $\mathrm{e}$). In computer science, the situation isn't as clean because we often want to talk about things like a number of bits or the height of a binary tree and, in those cases, the most natural (*baddum-tsh*) logarithm to use is base-$2$.  Some authors use $\ln$ and $\lg$ to explicitly denote base-$\mathrm{e}$ and base-$2$ logs, respectively; many authors just write $\log$ to mean whatever base is most appropriate for the situation.

Of course, Wikipedia is written by a huge number of unconnected authors, so you can't assume any consistent convention is used. Indeed, a careful Wikipedia editor would make sure that $\log$ is used consistently within an article, but you can't rely on everyone being careful.

**It usually doens't matter.** Changing the base of a logarithm just multiplies the answer by a constant factor because, for all $a,b>1$ and all $x>0$,
$$\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}\,.$$
In many situations, this multiplicative factor of $1/\log_b a$ isnt at all important. In the context of a [big-$O$, big-$\Theta$, big-$\Omega$ etc bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $O(\log n)$ means the same thing regardless of the base, since big-$O$ disregards constant factors. (But note that, e.g., $2^{\log_2 x}=x$, whereas $2^{\log_3 x}=x^{1/\log_2 3}\approx x^{1.58}$ so there are situations in which the base makes a big difference.)

**Your specific example.** In [a comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96355/what-kind-of-logarithm-log-means-in-wikipedia-articles#comment205196_96356), you say you're specifically interested in the [page about tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). I know nothing about document retrieval but my understanding from skim-reading that article is as follows. We're interested in ranking documents according to their relevance, and the relevance of a document is given by a score of the form $x\log y$, where $x$ and $y$ are statistics of the document. Since changing the base of the logarithm just multiplies all the scores by a constant, it doesn't change the ranking order. Therefore, it doesn't matter what base you use for the logarithm in this situation.